# How to count frequency of different elements of a column with a condition of another column element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I Have a data frame **‘df’** which looks like the table below.

| Job Title | Job Description |
| --- | --- |
| Data Scientist | xxxxx.., Python, R, Machine Learning, Deep Learning, NLP, Power BI, Tableau, Excel, spark, aws, MS Access, LMS, SAS, xxxx |
| Data Scientist | xxxxx..Python, R, Machine Learning, Deep Learning, NLP, Spark...xxxx |
| Data Analyst | xxxx...Python, SQL, Power BI, Tableau, ...xxx |
| Data Analyst | xxxx...Python, SQL, Power BI, Excel, ...xxx |
| ... | ... |

I want to count the frequency of each skills (python, R, etc) for the job title 'Data Scientist.
The result should look like -

```
| Skills | Frequency |
| -------- | -------------- |
| python    | 846            |
| R   | 165           |
| ...  | ...          |
```

My attempt for this was -

```
def freq (skill):
    count = 0
    if df["Job Title"]=="Data Scientist":
        for i in df["Job Description"]:
            if i == skill:
                count = count + 1
                return count
```

This gives error, even if it wouldn't then each skill needs to be fed one by one within the function. Is there any more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Please provide full desired output

Comment: The desired out is a dataframe with two columns. one is 'Job Title' and the second is 'Skill Frequency'.Please have a loon onto the original Data frame. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7IUtw-IF08OpuJhbRHwDsOYN_6cGaun/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `split`, `explode` and `groupby.value_counts`:

```
(df
 .assign(**{'Job Description': df['Job Description'].str.split(',\s*')})
 .explode('Job Description')
 .groupby('Job Title')['Job Description'].value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
Job Title       Job Description 
Data Analyst    ...xxx              2
                Power BI            2
                SQL                 2
                xxxx...Python       2
                Excel               1
                Tableau             1
Data Scientist  Deep Learning       2
                Machine Learning    2
                NLP                 2
                ...
                xxxxx..Python       1
Name: Job Description, dtype: int64
```

If you're just interested in 'Data Scientist', subset first:

```
(df
 .loc[df['Job Title'].eq('Data Scientist'), 'Job Description']
 .str.split(',\s*')
 .explode()
 .value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
R                   2
Machine Learning    2
Deep Learning       2
NLP                 2
xxxxx..             1
MS Access           1
...
Power BI            1
Spark...xxxx        1
Name: Job Description, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['Data Scientist', ['Python', 'R', 'Machine Learning', 'Deep Learning', 'NLP', 'Power BI', 'Tableau', 'Excel', 'spark', 'aws', 'MS Access', 'LMS', 'SAS']],
    ['Data Scientist', ['Python', 'R', 'Machine Learning', 'Deep Learning', 'NLP', 'Spark']],
    ['Data Analyst', ['Python', 'SQL', 'Power BI', 'Tableau']],
    ['Data Analyst', ['Python', 'SQL', 'Power BI', 'Excel']]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Job Title', 'Job Description'])

df_ds = df[df['Job Title'] == 'Data Scientist']
skills = set().union(*[set(s) for s in df_ds['Job Description']])
result = pd.DataFrame(0, index=skills, columns=['Frequency'])
for desc in df_ds['Job Description']:
    result.loc[desc, :] += 1
print(result)
```

prints

| index | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| Machine Learning | 2 |
| R | 2 |
| spark | 1 |
| SAS | 1 |
| aws | 1 |
| MS Access | 1 |
| Spark | 1 |
| NLP | 2 |
| Tableau | 1 |
| Python | 2 |
| Deep Learning | 2 |
| LMS | 1 |
| Excel | 1 |
| Power BI | 1 |

If the Job Description column contains full texts instead of lists of only skills, you need to first convert from strings to lists of strings (e.g. words) and then filter out any non-skill words, e.g. as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# get list of common english words
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/98d35708fa344717d8eee15d11987de6c8e26d7d/1-1000.txt'
commonwords = set(requests.get(url).text.split('\n'))
# load dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('glassdoor_jobs.csv')
# convert strings to lists of strings
df['Job Description'] = df['Job Description'].apply(lambda s: s.split())
# filter out all non data scientist jobs
df_ds = df[df['Job Title'] == 'Data Scientist']
# filter out any non skill words (proxied via excluding overall most common words)
skills = set().union(*[set(s) for s in df_ds['Job Description']])
skills = sorted({sk.lower() for sk in skills} - commonwords)

result = pd.DataFrame(0, index=skills, columns=['Frequency'])
for desc in df_ds['Job Description']:
    kws = sorted({s.lower() for s in set(desc)} - commonwords)
    result.loc[kws, :] += 1
result.sort_values(by='Frequency', inplace=True, ascending=False)

print(result.head(20))
```

prints

| index | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| data | 176 |
| learning | 129 |
| scientist | 127 |
| years | 120 |
| business | 116 |
| skills | 112 |
| using | 111 |
| models | 111 |
| statistical | 109 |
| analysis | 108 |
| working | 106 |
| knowledge | 106 |
| ability | 101 |
| solutions | 99 |
| tools | 95 |
| computer | 92 |
| analytics | 91 |
| technical | 89 |
| teams | 86 |
| development | 85 |

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. It's working well with the above 'data'. But the actual data is a data frame with many rows for 'Job Title' and 'Job Description'.  I have tried converting the Data Frame into a list but it's not working.  link to the data frame : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7IUtw-IF08OpuJhbRHwDsOYN_6cGaun/view?usp=sharing

Comment: see second part of my edited answer

Comment: Dear Michael Your code worked well but What if I provide the skills list (Python, R, C/C++, Java, Machine Learning, Deep Learning, NLP, Power BI, Tableau, Excel, spark, aws, MS Access, LMS, SAS) for Data Scientist Job. Could you please modify the code?