# How to count frequencies of different words from a dataframe column when the words are provided in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame **df** which is a web scrapped data of Jobs and Job descriptions from glassdoor and it looks like this -

| Job Title | Job Description |
| --- | --- |
| Data Scientist | Descripton |
| Data Scientist | Descripton |
| Data Engineer | Descripton |
| Data Scientist | Descripton |
| Data Analyst | Descripton |

It has columns for **Job Title** and **Job Description**. Job Descriptions are huge and have all the descriptions for a particular Job Title including the required skills somewhere in the middle of Job Description.

Screen Shot of one of the Job Description is below -

[image]

I am trying to get a dataframe with two columns, **skills** and **frequency** for the **Job Title Data Scientist**.

**skills should be (list):** Python, R, C/C++, Java, Machine Learning, Deep Learning, NLP, Power BI, Tableau, Excel, spark, aws, MS Access, LMS, SAS.

**Frequency:** The number of times a skill is found in all Job descriptions for the Data Scientist Job Title

**The output should be a dataframe that would look like this -**

| skills | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| python | 243 |
| R | 109 |
| power bi | 183 |
| tableau | 201 |

and so on.

My take on this was:

```
(df
 .loc[df['Job Title'].eq('Data Scientist'), 'Job Description']
 .str.split(',\s*')
 .explode()
 .value_counts()
)
```

But this gives the frequency of each word from the description.

Another way I tried:

```
test = df['Job Description'].apply(lambda x: 1 if 'python' in x.lower()else 0)
test.value_counts()
```

This gives the count of skill but the problem with this approach is that the skills need to be fed one by one.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible input directly in the question and the matching expected output.

Comment: Also, is this an assignment? We've similar questions today... Actually your code is [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73321554/how-to-count-frequency-of-different-elements-of-a-column-with-a-condition-of-ano/73321701#73321701)

Comment: Dear mozway, I am the same guy from a different account. This is not an assignment. I am just trying to learn something which not available online.  I am a working professional from Biology filed and new to python. I am learning it on my own. what I want to do is, I want to make a table based on the dataframe provided which would show how important are the given skills for a job. The number of times a skill is found in a job description the more important it is. I need a two-column table with skills and its frequency in the different job descriptions. Could you please help?

Comment: My code from the other question worked fine for the provided example. It looks like you have a completely different format here (not simply comma separated keywords). The key is that you need to be able to extract the keywords. This is the real question. Solve this and my previous answer should work fine.

Comment: If it would have been SQL I would have used the 'Like' function to extract the keywords and their frequency from the data frame, but in python I have no idea.

Comment: I provided an answer below (disclaimer, I couldn't access your file so I didn't test it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't check the online file, but if I understand correctly you can use a regex to extract the terms;

```
l = ['Python', 'R', 'C/C++', 'Java', 'Machine Learning', 'Deep Learning', 'NLP', 'Power BI', 'Tableau', 'Excel', 'spark', 'aws', 'MS Access', 'lLMS', 'SAS']

import re

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, l))
# 'Python|R|C/C\\+\\+|Java|Machine\\ Learning|Deep\\ Learning|NLP|Power\\ BI|Tableau|Excel|spark|aws|MS\\ Access|lLMS|SAS'

(df
 .set_index('Job Title') # set index what you want to group on later
 ['Job Description']
 .str.extractall(f'({regex})')[0]
 .groupby(level=0)
 .value_counts()
)
```